# Using Perl to Display GPX File on Google Map

Tags: perl, google-maps, gpx

I have a bunch of GPX files on our server and would like to overlay them on top of a Google Map to display them on our website. We use Perl for all our site scripts however we're having a hard time figuring out how to format the data correctly to display it in Google Maps.

I'm hoping that some GPX expert out there can explain at a high level how we can best accomplish this and provide some sample perl code to correctly process the GPX file and print out the necessary HTML to display it on a Google Map.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you really want to use is [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/). If you want a somewhat perlish interface to it, rather than just driving it from the commandline, there's also a [GPS::Babel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/GPS::Babel) module.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Hobbs! Once I read the GPX file in using GPSBabel, how do I then output it in the correct format for being displayed on a Google map. Have you seen a good example somewhere?

Comment: You tell gpsbabel to convert from gpx to kml.

Comment: Ok, so you now have a KML file. So how do you then overlay that on Google Maps?

Comment: Any idea how to overlay a KML file on a Google Map?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers